# How big is the area/radius that prevents neutral creep spawns?

Tags: dota-2, dota

It is a known fact that putting wards inside the neutral spawn camps prevents them from spawning but recently, I see our neutrals camps not spawning any creeps.
I checked the replay and saw that the opposing team put the ward behind the neutral camp instead of the usual in-front.

This is new to me so now I ask how big is the radius(or area) that the game checks? I always thought is was a triangular area in front of the neutral camp.

EDIT:
If the vision of the neutrals camps prevents them from spawning, then how come this ward does not prevent them from respawning?
[image: neutral camp respawned]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the spawn boxes for the radiant side of the map courtesy of http://dota-2.co/topic/4159-neutral-camp-spawn-points/:

[image]

Comment: I added an image where the ward vision did not prevent the neutral camp from re-spawning.

Comment: @MegaNairda you are right, I'm updating my answer after doing some digging.  Learn something new about dota 2 every day :)

Comment: Wow. So those rocks, bushes and flowers are actually like markers/

Comment: @meganairda not sure if its intentional or it just so happens that the boundary is near those items

Comment: @MegaNairda There are plenty of markers like those that seem intentional. Many indicate tower range, as well.

Comment: @spartacus Yeah respawns have nothing to do with vision, but that's a pretty common misconception.