# How to stack ancient creeps in Dota2

Tags: dota-2

I know you can stack regular creeps by getting them from their camp before next minute, so that if they are not in camp for example between 9:59 - 10:00 new creepts will spawn there.

However this doesn't always work for ancient creeps. Sometimes they spawn, sometimes not. Why? Is the timing different there?

Comment: Check this related question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95464/how-big-is-the-area-radius-that-prevents-neutral-creep-spawns

Comment: It's not so mucfh about timing than spawn box size. Technically stackign at xx:53-55 should work until there are too many ancient and you have to try at 52/53.

Comment: is there some picture that shows the spawn box size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timing isn't different at all. Could you be more specific as to which side you've tried to stack from, and failed? If you're on the Radiant side, it is far more effective to **run straight south** along the ridge instead of turning north towards the secret shop. If you turn north, you  force them to take a path that results in them gaining less distance, and they go home faster. They will usually get stuck on the trees a bit while trying to chase you, which is what causes that.

If you are playing a character with a long range physical ability, like Beastmaster, then casting your spell from "behind" the camp (where the secret shop is, in the Radiant, or directly from the offlane in the Dire) and targeting the spot where the creeps are will also work 100% of the time if you time it correctly.

If you were in the middle of a real match and your ancients would not stack, and you're **quite sure** that you performed the stack properly, then someone probably warded your ancient camp. You will want to buy sentry wards and try to remove it. It's best to look up videos for good ward placement, as you can easily accidentally block your own camp while doing this. EDIT: @ywm's suggestion in the comments to the OP has some *very* useful graphics regarding this topic.

Comment: That warding might be what caused them not to spawn, that I didn't consider

Comment: It's bad that there is no map similar to the linked question that would show ancient creeps it's also possible that if the box is too large, I was still in it

Comment: BTW "if you are sure that you stacked properly" - this is pretty much what my question is - how do I stack properly? Maybe I am doing it wrong. All I know is timing which is every minute

Comment: By that I meant you're sure you got the timing right. You know to pull at the :53 second mark, right? As in, you should click on the creep right at the :53 second mark and let your autoattack animation do the rest. If you are melee I recommend standing just outside of creep vision and run in at the :51-52 second mark, and run away as soon as they start following.

Comment: Some key pointers on ward locations near ancient creeps; on the Radiant side, as I'm sure you probably know, there's a tiny piece of the ridge to the right/east of the stairs nearest the ancients. This is not in the camp's vision and is a good offensive ward spot. Radiant ancients are rather dangerous for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a virtual map of the game.

http://devilesk.com/dota2/apps/interactivemap2/

You can tick the box under the Overlays section to toggle on Neutral Camps Spawn Boxes.

The trick is to have all of the ancients outside of this box to make another camp spawn. I usually pull around the x:53 mark.

You can also use this virtual map to practice placing wards to see what does and doesn't block the neutral camps.